# Determining the pixel length of a string in Cocoa (MAC OSX)

Tags: cocoa, string, macos

I need to figure out the pixel length of an NSString in Cocoa on OSX and I have found a couple of links that describe how to do this using the IPhone sdk but I didn't see anything about how to do this when not targeting the IPhone.  Can anyone link me to some docs that would be relevant.  I did find anything in the NSString docs.

Comment: Don't think about pixels—they are an artifact of a device. Unless you're talking to a device directly, or working with a raster (“bitmap”) buffer directly, you are not working with pixels. Vector operations, including the measurement and drawing of strings, work with user space units: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Transforms/Transforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290-CH204-SW5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[-[NSString sizeWithAttributes:]](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithAttributes:)

Comment: as a side note: the reason you couldn't find it in the NSString docs is that it is dependent on several things in AppKit, so it belongs in a separate category.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what i use to get the size of a string...

```
NSSize size = [@"Some text" sizeWithAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue Bold" size:24.0f] forKey:NSFontAttributeName]];
```

**NOTE:** If you are adding the string to a textfield, i have found that you need to add about 10 to size.width for it to fit.